# Unable to load resource image from another assembly

Tags: c#, wpf

**Case**

I've got two assemblies: one holding the application, one acting as library.
The library holds and image resource, say: "Images/image.png" with its build action set to **resource**.

**Library**

Next to that, the library contains a SomeStyle.xaml file:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

     <Image x:Key="someKey" Source="/LibraryAssemblyHere;component/Images/image.png" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Application**

The application assembly has the App.xaml with:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/LibraryAssemblyHere;component/Styles/SomeStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Problem**

When starting the application, Visual Studio 2010 gives me the following error:

```
Failed to create a 'ImageSource' from the text '/LibraryAssemblyHere;component/Images/image.png
```

With an inner exception:

```
Cannot locate resource 'images/image.png'.
```

**Question**

Simple: *What am I doing wrong?* I've searched and searched, but nothing helped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the library has the image in it, there's no need for pack URI syntax in the resources file, which is also in the library.

Comment: Oke, fair enough. You know what... That actually fixed it for some reason. I thought the pack syntax was just a longer version and should point to the same resources. Apparently it dos not. Can anyone shed light on this?